# How to solve a diophantine equation $\, j\, a + k\, b = n\, ab\,$ for $a,b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I was preparing for the Maclaurin Olympiad and I came across this question:

Show that:
$$ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{5}{11}$$
has no solutions for positive integers $a,b$.

Is there any general method to solve equations like this:

$$11a + 11b = 5ab$$

Thank you

Comment: This is a FAQ. Unfortunately the prior answers are not well-organized. You can find some of the prior answers by searching on ["completing square product"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+completing+square+product), the buzzwords that  I use for this. I'd like to encourage others to help organize these topics - rather than increase the disorganization by posting yet more duplicate answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way: rewrite as
$$ (5a - 11)(5b-11) = 11^2 $$
and consider all ways of factoring the right side.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105505/discussion-on-answer-by-robert-israel-how-to-solve-a-diophantine-equation-j).

Answer (score 1):

Now express one of them, say $b$: $$b(5a-11)=11a$$ so $$5a-11\mid 11a$$

so $$5a-11 \mid 5\cdot 11a-11(5a-11) =121$$

so $$5a-11\in \{-1,1,-11,11,-121,121\}$$

so $$5a\in \{10,13,0,22,-110,132\}$$ so $a=2$ or $a=0$ or $a=-22$. Clealy, noone fits.

Comment: Then note that in the original question involving fractions, $a=0$ is not allowed, and $a=2 \Rightarrow b=-22$ so there are no solutions in the positive integers, which is what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can just eliminate possibilities.

- Both must be greater than $2$ as otherwise the sum exceeds $\frac12>\frac5 {11}$
- One must be a multiple of $11$ since $5ab=11(a+b)$ and $11$ is prime. So the other must be no bigger than $\frac{11}{4}$ since $\frac{1}{\frac{11}{4}}+\frac{1}{11} = \frac{5}{11}$
- But $3 =\frac{12}{4}>\frac{11}{4}$, so there are no possibilities

Answer (score 0):

If $a=b$, so $$\frac{2}{a}=\frac{5}{11},$$ which is impossible.

Let $a>b$.

Thus, $$\frac{5}{11}<\frac{2}{b}$$ or
$$b<\frac{22}{5},$$ which gives $$b\leq4.$$
In another hand, $$\frac{1}{b}<\frac{5}{11}$$ or
$$b>\frac{11}{5},$$ which gives $$b\geq3.$$
Now, easy to check that for $b\in\{3,4\}$ we can not get a natural value of $a$.